# Box2D OpenGl Error

Tags: c++, box2d, physics-engine

I get an error with Box2D. The Building process of the Testbed is working very well. But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Error compiling shader of type 35633!
0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
Error compiling shader of type 35632!
0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
Testbed:/home/amrit/Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Framework/DebugDraw.cpp:176: GLuint sCreateShaderProgram(const char*, const char*): Assertion `vsId != 0 && fsId != 0' failed.
[1]    14679 abort (core dumped)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add a [mcve] (aka your code), in order to help us find a solution.

Comment: The error explicitly states what's wrong, you're trying to use GLSL 3.30 shaders but they aren't supported. The reason it builds find and fails when run is because your shaders are only compiled at run time

Comment: This is not a programming question. Update your graphics drivers or get a better graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your graphics driver would fix this problem.

Alternatively, you can hack the Box2D Testbed sources to instead request the version 3.0 OpenGL support. It seems you have that but 3.0 may not support everything that the Testbed needs (YMMV).